# Apache Vysper with Smack 4.1.8 client library - how to handle the TLS certificate?

Tags: xmpp, smack, apache-vysper

I want to connect to an Apache Vysper Server using the Smack 4.1.8 library. But how to handle the bogus_mina_tls.crt that comes with Vysper? In Smack 3 you just could use:

```
ConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new ConnectionConfiguration("localhost", 5222);
connectionConfiguration.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
connectionConfiguration.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
connectionConfiguration.setKeystorePath("src/main/resources/bogus_mina_tls.cert");
connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePath("src/main/resources/bogus_mina_tls.cert");
connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePassword("boguspw");
```

But how to do that in the Smack 4 API with the `XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()` ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Smack 4 you need to to construct the `SSLContext` for Smack yourself and set it with `setCustomSslContext(SSLContext)`. If you don't provide a custom `SSLContext` then Smack will use the runtime's default (i.e. resort to verifying the certificate with Java's truststore).

Comment: and do i need the certificate also? how to set this up? could you give me a tutorial or something like this.... sorry i am quite new to ssl ;)